# Assemble Overview tikz Tree from Smaller Trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, organisation

I'm keep a large org chart in TikZ, and I like being able to render it in total, but it's cumbersome to handle when one only wants to see a single team (branch of tree). Does anybody know how I can instead define each branch of the tree, rendering the branches individually, as well as rendering them as related to one another, but only having to update the individual branches, and having the overview/aggregate tree referenced to the individual branches?

So this is what I've got now, though of course, the real thing is much, much larger and more cumbersome when rendered:

```
% WHAT I HAVE NOW (OVERVIEW, GIANT TABLE)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,calc,angles,positioning,intersections}
\tikzset{font=\small, level distance=7cm}
\tikzset{grow=right}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west,minimum height=8mm,rectangle,rounded corners,draw=black,thin,align=left,text depth=0pt}}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw,edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east)-- +(0,0pt)-| (\tikzchildnode.west)}}}
\tikzset{sibling distance=1cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.{Leader 1}
        [.{Manager 1}
                [.{Individual Contributor 1} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 2} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 3} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 4} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 5} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 6} ]
        ]
        [.{Manager 2}
                [.{Individual Contributor 7} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 8} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 9} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 10} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 11} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 12} ]
        ]
        [.{Manager 3}
                [.{Individual Contributor 13} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 14} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 15} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 16} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 17} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 18} ]
        ]
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the kind of thing I'm going for:

```
% WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,calc,angles,positioning,intersections}
\tikzset{font=\small, level distance=7cm}
\tikzset{grow=right}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west,minimum height=8mm,rectangle,rounded corners,draw=black,thin,align=left,text depth=0pt}}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw,edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east)-- +(0,0pt)-| (\tikzchildnode.west)}}}
\tikzset{sibling distance=1cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} % TEAM ONE (SUBTREE TWO)
        \Tree [.{Manager 1}
                [.{Individual Contributor 1} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 2} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 3} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 4} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 5} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 6} ]
        ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} % TEAM TWO (SUBTREE TWO)
        \Tree [.{Manager 2}
                [.{Individual Contributor 7} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 8} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 9} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 10} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 11} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 12} ]
        ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} % TEAM THREE (SUBTREE THREE)
        \Tree [.{Manager 3}
                [.{Individual Contributor 13} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 14} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 15} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 16} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 17} ]
                [.{Individual Contributor 18} ]
        ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} % THE OVERVIEW TREE, WITH EVERYTHING
\Tree [.{Leader 1}
        % SUBTREE ONE / OF MANAGER 1
        % SUBTREE TWO / OF MANAGER 2
        % SUBTREE THREE / OF MANAGER 3
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Forest can do this. Or you can save the teams in save boxes and then include them in nodes in the main tree.

Comment: Please can you complete your code so people can compile it? I guess you need a package, as well as a document class.

Comment: Done, thanks for the feedback... my first post, so I didn't realize classes were appropriate to add in code examples.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes, it can be hard or impossible to guess the right way to complete an example - and it is always easier not to paste and example and immediately reproduce an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could save the trees to save boxes and then reuse them in nodes in the final tree. Or you could use Forest. The following solution includes a less horrible hack, [courtesy of Sašo Živanović](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382769/how-can-i-get-correct-spacing-when-reusing-forest-trees-and-when-calign-is-cente?noredirect=1#comment947335_382769) to workaround a bug when reusing the trees in the combined tree.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  default preamble={
    for tree={
      align=center,
      child anchor=parent,
      draw,
    },
  },
  merge/.style={% less horrible hack from Sašo Živanović: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382769/how-can-i-get-correct-spacing-when-reusing-forest-trees-and-when-calign-is-cente?noredirect=1#comment947335_382769
    replace by=#1,
    for group={name=#1, first}{s=0}
  }
}

\Forest*{
  [Manager 1, name=m1
    [Individual\\Contributor 1]
    [Individual\\Contributor 2]
    [Individual\\Contributor 3]
    [Individual\\Contributor 4]
    [Individual\\Contributor 5]
    [Individual\\Contributor 6]
  ]
}

\Forest*{
  [Manager 2, name=m2
    [Individual\\Contributor 7]
    [Individual\\Contributor 8]
    [Individual\\Contributor 9]
    [Individual\\Contributor 10]
    [Individual\\Contributor 11]
    [Individual\\Contributor 12]
  ]
}

\Forest*{
  [Manager 3, name=m3
    [Individual\\Contributor 13]
    [Individual\\Contributor 14]
    [Individual\\Contributor 15]
    [Individual\\Contributor 16]
    [Individual\\Contributor 17]
    [Individual\\Contributor 18]
  ]
}

\Forest*{
  [Leader 1
    [, merge=m1]
    [, merge=m2]
    [, merge=m3]
  ]
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Forest combinations]

## EDIT

Here's a modified version which emulates the style applied to the tree in the current version of the question.

[image: styled version]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  default preamble={
    for tree={
      align=center,
      child anchor=parent,
      draw,
      grow'=0,
      rounded corners,
      parent anchor=children,
      anchor=parent,
      edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -| (.child anchor)},
    },
  },
  merge/.style={% less horrible hack from Sašo Živanović: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382769/how-can-i-get-correct-spacing-when-reusing-forest-trees-and-when-calign-is-cente?noredirect=1#comment947335_382769
    replace by=#1,
    for nodewalk={fake={name=#1}, last, fake=parent, first}{s'=0pt},
  }
}

\Forest*{
  [Manager 1, name=m1
    [Individual Contributor 1]
    [Individual Contributor 2]
    [Individual Contributor 3]
    [Individual Contributor 4]
    [Individual Contributor 5]
    [Individual Contributor 6]
  ]
}

\Forest*{
  [Manager 2, name=m2
    [Individual Contributor 7]
    [Individual Contributor 8]
    [Individual Contributor 9]
    [Individual Contributor 10]
    [Individual Contributor 11]
    [Individual Contributor 12]
  ]
}

\Forest*{
  [Manager 3, name=m3
    [Individual Contributor 13]
    [Individual Contributor 14]
    [Individual Contributor 15]
    [Individual Contributor 16]
    [Individual Contributor 17]
    [Individual Contributor 18]
  ]
}

\Forest*{
  [Leader 1
    [, merge=m1]
    [, merge=m2]
    [, merge=m3]
  ]
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/382769/