# How can I get correct spacing when reusing Forest trees and when calign is center (default), last etc.?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-trees, trees, forest

Forest allows me to reuse (part of) a tree in another tree. However, when `calign` has certain values, including the default `center`, this does strange things to the spacing of some nodes. How can this be avoided in a less hackish way than by the use of the commented code block, which is a really horrible workaround?

The following example is based on [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/382767/) to [David Emerson's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/382756/).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  default preamble={
    for tree={
      align=center,
      child anchor=parent,
      draw,
    },
%     before packing={% horrible hack - this shouldn't be needed at all!
%       where={>On=On=&{n}{1}{n children}{0}}{
%         if nodewalk valid={next}{
%           s'+=100mm,
%         }{}
%       }{},
%     }
  },
}

\Forest*{
  [Manager 1, name=m1
    [Individual\\Contributor 1]
    [Individual\\Contributor 2]
    [Individual\\Contributor 3]
    [Individual\\Contributor 4]
    [Individual\\Contributor 5]
    [Individual\\Contributor 6]
  ]
}


\Forest*{
    [, replace by=m1]
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Unwanted spacing oddities]

Comment: I can confirm this is a bug: packing a node only works when `s=0` for the first child. I'll investigate when (and why) this bug was introduced. Until then, a less horrible hack: ;-)  set `s=0` for "Individual Contributor 1" in the preamble of the second tree, e.g. `for group={name=m1,first}{s=0}`.  (As it doesn't hurt to set `s` of other nodes (before packing), one could also set `s=0` for all nodes in the "combined" tree, like `for name={m1}{for tree={s=0}}`.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Thanks. But then I would have to do that explicitly for every sub-tree merged into the main tree, right? (In the original question, there were 3 such trees, but I think the OP's original document has many more. And `s=0` won't be correct for most of the merged was-a-root cases, will it? Or have I just misunderstood something again?

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Never mind. I can wrap it in a style, of course. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/382767/ ... Thank you :-).

Comment: @SašoŽivanović This bug persists in current Forest? (And in a slightly later version I have from you.)

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Did you get to the bottom of this? ;)